# find files that start with a 6 digit number and matches number from the list

Tags: shell, files

I have a big number of files   around 185000, 99% of then start with a 6 digit number follow by underscore and other random symbols and random extensions

```
 312095_ck_image-24-10-20-11-29-1.jpeg
 312095_ck_image-24-10-20-11-29-2.jpeg
  312095_ck_image-24-10-20-11-29.jpeg
```

Basically this six digit number is a userid(user id  given by some backend oracle db),
each of the user ids can appear multiple times  in a directory. I also have a text file of  6 digit numbers one per each line( around 18000 numbers) . Is it possible to match  files  directory with the content of a text file.
So if a file starts with a number that is in the text file I  want it  moved to another directory(regardless off the rest of the name or extension) so I can delete that folder later. I just want all the matching files in one folder so I can delete entire folder and not each individual files.  Is this even possible in Linux (in shell or by installing/building from source some other Linux program). OS version is RHEL Linux 6.
If it makes this any easier I can load a list of files in a directory to a db table  and match it against the list of numbers I have in a  text file, so I can know exactly what is the of the file to be re/moved. I just don't know how to then feed  that list to mv command so it can move/delete the files.  what's the  easiest way to achieve it?
So if my actual folder Is `/new_upload/entrants/` and I have a empty folder called junk on the same level as  entrants  `/new upload/junk`  and if 312095 apears inside a list of ids I  want to execute

```
mv 312095_*   /new_upload/junk 

[idis] entrants# sh -h
sh-4.1# 
[idis] entrants# $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Start with the `grep` manpage, particularly the `-f` flag which allows you to pass a filename full of patterns (your file of user IDs).  Also, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533019/233270) which talks generally about how to approach problems with a simple text-based approach to where you're actually **creating** a script, instead of executing one.  IMO, it is much more conducive to learning, experimentation and testing, while minimizing the risk of damage or malfunction.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your post to tell us what shell you're using and show us the sample commands you would like to have executed on the three sample files for user ID 312095. If files can be in various directories, please include some examples that demonstrate that.

Comment: with the same effort you could move, you could just as well delete the right files … so that moving seems to  be a "decoy", something you don't actually need but makes your problem a bit more complicated

Comment: You really need tools like RANGER or FZF for this job. Install them and try before doing anything else.

Comment: @–Marcus Müller The only reason  I want to mv the files instead of just deleting them  just  to know the size of junk folder and possibly double check before making such a drastic change to the fie system

Comment: that makes no sense. "Junk folders" are a thing that only file manager applications know, just delete the file, no trash folder involved. and regarding drastic changes: either you want to delete all these non-six-digit-files, or you don't. Your computer is quite good at selecting files starting with six digits, I dare say it's better than your eye! Anyway, you can just `echo "${file}"` instead of `rm "${file}"` and get a list of files that *would* have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

On a GNU system, you could do:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -F/ '
    !list_processed {user[$0]; next}
    match($NF, /^([0-9]{6})_/, f) && f[1] in user
    ' user-list.txt list_processed=1 RS='\0' ORS='\0' - |
  xargs -r0 mv -it /where/to/move/them --
```

Answer (score 0):

You have GNU `bash`, so this is straightforward using shell constructs and GNU `grep`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
  match=$(echo "${file}" | grep -o '^[[:digit:]]\{6\}')
  if [[ -z "${match}" ]] ;  then
    # File did not start with 6 digits, delete
    rm -- "${file}"
  else
    grep -q -F ${match} numbersfile.txt || rm -- "${file}"
  fi
done
```

that is:

- loop over all file names
- for each file name, check using `grep` whether it starts with 6 digits
- if not, delete file
- if so, check using `grep` whether the matching digits are in `numbersfile.txt`
- if not, delete file

(if you want to test before deleting, just replace `rm` with `echo` and you'll get the list of all files to be deleted)